# The sum of elements in an array

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-array

I'm new to bash script learning and I'm quiet confused how to do this code.

```bsh
array1=(23 34 23 12 11 32 12 12 12 21)
array2=(12 13 14 43 42 23 32 11 10 22)
```

These are the two arrays, and I need to get the sum of the elements, as an example 23+12, 34+13 etc. and the output should be, `Result 1: xx` (the sum) to all the 10 elements in the array. How can I code this using a C-style loop?

Comment: Can you include some details on what you've tried and in what ways what you've tried didn't solve your problem?

Comment: The way I have tried it's just gives me the sum of the array. But I need to add the elements. That's why I need help

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another option:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

array1=(23 34 23 12 11 32 12 12 12 21)
array2=(12 13 14 43 42 23 32 11 10 22)

for ((i = 0; i < ${#array1[@]} && i < ${#array2[@]}; i++)); do
    printf "Result %2d: %d\n" $((i + 1)) $((array1[i] + array2[i]))
done
```

An example run:

```
Result  1: 35
Result  2: 47
Result  3: 37
Result  4: 55
Result  5: 53
Result  6: 55
Result  7: 44
Result  8: 23
Result  9: 22
Result 10: 43
```

The script runs a loop from 0 up until the length of the shortest array (just in case some future change made one longer than the other).  Each time through the loop it prints the result for the i-th entry.

Comment: Thank you! This is c-style loop I was looking for.

Comment: @Grace That's an arithmetic `for` loop. It's unclear what you mean by "C-style loop". The `bash` manual does not mention "C-style loops" at all.

Comment: @Kusalananda, well, given that the syntax of a for loop in C is for (expr1; expr2; expr3) stmt; (give or take some details), it really [doesn't require much](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+c-style+loop) imagination to see what a "C-style (for) loop" might mean in the shell.

Comment: @ilkkachu `while sometest; do ...; done` is awfully similar to the C loop `while (sometest) { ... }`.  If it matters to them, they might want to say exactly what they require, and why. I find it strange to want answers that uses _particular_ types of loops even if those kinds of loop are not suited for solving the problem.  Remember that arrays in `bash` are _sparse_ for example, so that iterating over _indexes_ with an arithmetic `for` loop may not correctly access all elements.

Comment: @Kusalananda, sure, `i=0; while (( i++ < 5 )); do echo $i; done` would also be somewhat C-like. The fun thing is that Bash, Ksh and Zsh also support `for (( i=0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )) { echo $i; }`, which should probably be called _the_ C-style loop -- just the parens are doubled. If it's useful to do that it that way, or why someone would want to is indeed a different question. IMO, there''s a slight smell of homework assignment there, and that might explain some things.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
array1=(23 34 23 12 11 32 12 12 12 21)
array2=(12 13 14 43 42 23 32 11 10 22)

# Declare array3 as an array
array3=()

for i in $( seq 1 $((${#array1[@]}+1)) ); do
   array3+=( $(( ${array1[i]} + ${array2[i]} )) );
   printf 'Result %d : %s\n' "$i" "${array3[i]}";
done
```

Output:

```
Result 1 : 47
Result 2 : 37
Result 3 : 55
Result 4 : 53
Result 5 : 55
Result 6 : 44
Result 7 : 23
Result 8 : 22
Result 9 : 43
```

Comment: This adds the two elements but how can I get the output like this,   Result 1 xx, Result 2 xx .....

Comment: `for i in ${array3[@]}; do echo "Result $i : ${array3[$i]}; done`

Comment: @ikkachu.  Updated. Good points.  I don't use `ksh` much

Comment: Is this the c-style loop?

Comment: @Grace .  It's a bash-style loop.  You'll have to be more specific about what you expect by "C-style".  You should have all of the tools you need here:  Declaring arrays, accessing elements, appending elements, accessing array size, looping through each element, addition.

Comment: Thank you! I'll continue the code with the help of yours

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
array1=(23 34 23 12 11 32 12 12 12 21)
array2=(12 13 14 43 42 23 32 11 10 22)

set -- "${array1[@]}"

unset counter
for elem in "${array2[@]}"; do
        set -- "$@" "$((++counter))" "$(( $1 + elem ))"
        shift
done

printf 'Result %d: %d\n' "$@"
```

This loops over all the elements of one of the arrays (the second), and for each element, `$elem`, it adds a counter and the sum to the list of positional parameters.

The sum is calculated by adding `$elem` to the first positional parameter, `$1` (which is then shifted off the list).  The positional parameters were initialized to the elements of the first list, so this effectively pairs the elements up.

After the loop, the positional parameters contains the counter values paired up with the sums.  These are then printed with `printf`.

The output would be

```
Result 1: 35
Result 2: 47
Result 3: 37
Result 4: 55
Result 5: 53
Result 6: 55
Result 7: 44
Result 8: 23
Result 9: 22
Result 10: 43
```

You could obviously print the results directly in the loop too:

```bsh
array1=(23 34 23 12 11 32 12 12 12 21)
array2=(12 13 14 43 42 23 32 11 10 22)

set -- "${array1[@]}"

unset counter
for elem in "${array2[@]}"; do
        printf 'Result %d: %d\n' "$((++counter))" "$(( $1 + elem ))"
        shift
done
```

With a C-style `while` loop:

```bsh
array1=(23 34 23 12 11 32 12 12 12 21)
array2=(12 13 14 43 42 23 32 11 10 22)

set -- "${array1[@]}"

unset counter
while [ "$#" -ne 0 ]; do
        printf 'Result %d: %d\n' "$((++counter))" "$(( $1 + array2[counter-1] ))"
        shift
done
```

---

A pure `sh` variant:

```bsh
set -- 23 34 23 12 11 32 12 12 12 21

unset counter
for elem in 12 13 14 43 42 23 32 11 10 22; do
        printf 'Result %d: %d\n' "$((counter += 1))" "$(( $1 + elem ))"
        shift
done
```

---

Using `bc` and `paste`:

```bsh
array1=(23 34 23 12 11 32 12 12 12 21)
array2=(12 13 14 43 42 23 32 11 10 22)

paste -d '+' \
        <( printf 'print "Result ", ++c, ": ", %s\n' "${array1[@]}" ) \
        <( printf '%s, "\\n"\n' "${array2[@]}" ) |
bc
```

---

Using `awk` (features a C-style `for` loop!):

```bsh
array1=(23 34 23 12 11 32 12 12 12 21)
array2=(12 13 14 43 42 23 32 11 10 22)

awk     -v a="${array1[*]}" \
        -v b="${array2[*]}" \
        '
BEGIN {
        split(a,aa," ");
        n = split(b,bb," ");

        for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
                printf "Result %d: %d\n", i, aa[i]+bb[i]
}'
```

Comment: Thank you! This one is working!

Answer (score -1):

For the fun with dc
Sorry, the comments are in french.

```
#!/bin/bash
array1=(23 34 23 12 3211 32 12 2 12 21)
array2=(12 13 14 43 42 23 32 5 710 22)
dc <<EOF
# Definition
  # macro e = quitter si les tableaux n ont pas la meme taille
  # macro f = calcul du nb de digit du resultat et stocke le max dans registre p
  # macro g = addition des tableaux dans le registre tableau m
  # macro h = afficher les espaces pour le formattage
  # macro i = affichage du resultat formatte 
  # registre j = nb elt tableau
  # registre k = nb max de digit de l index du tableau
  # registre l = compteur elt tableau
  # registre m = tableau indexe de la somme des tableaux d entree
  # registre n = compteur du nb de digit de l index du tableau
  # registre o = nb max de digit pour affichage
  # registre p = nb max de digit du calcul
  # registre q = poubelle
# Strings
  [arrays are not the same size]sa
  [Result]sb
  [:]sc
  [ ]sd
# Macros
  [lapq]se
  [dZsp]sf
  [ll;m+dZlp<fll:mll1-dsl0<g]sg
  [lnd1+snldnlo>h]sh
  [ll1+dddsllbndZsnlksolhxnlcn;mdZsnlpsolhxpsqlj>i]si
# Program
  $(printf "%d\n" ${array1[*]})
  zdsjZsk
  $(printf "%d\n" ${array2[*]})
  zlj-lj!=e
  ljsllgxljsllgx
  lix
EOF
```

Display :

```
Result  1:   35  
Result  2:   47  
Result  3:   37  
Result  4:   55  
Result  5: 3253  
Result  6:   55  
Result  7:   44  
Result  8:    7  
Result  9:  722  
Result 10:   43
```

Comment: nice, the fun of dc get downvote.